# 2002 Jeep Grand Cherokee limited turn signals and emergency flashers not working

Tags: jeep, fuse, grand-cherokee, brake-light

I have replaced the relay in the dash. Also replaced the combination lever on the steering wheel and also put brand new tail lights in with new bulb sockets and lights. Nothing works. Another problem is when I hit the brake pedal the fuse for the brakes blow. Not sure if they are related

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you press the brake pedal do the brakes blow, or does the fuse for the brake lights blow?

Comment: I get it ... no I don't.   Wait. Oh, OK.

Comment: There's probably a short in the wiring which is what's causing the brake fuse to pop and the turn signals to not to blink.